# How to access the inside of the container without running the container

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Good morning.
I am currently using Docker version 19.03 on Mac OS X Catalina.
MariaDB 10.3 was installed in Docker, vim was installed to set the character-set, and /etc/mysql/my.cnf file was modified.

After modification, an attempt was made to restart to reflect, but it was not executed normally.
When I checked it with docker ps -a command, STATUS showed an Exited (1) error.

When I checked the log showing the error, I could check the following log.

unknown variable'collection-server=utf8_unicode_ci'

Stupidly there was a typo in the settings.

So I am trying to modify this setting, but there is no way to modify it because the docker container is not loaded.

docker-compose.yml is not in use.

The simplest way is to delete the Docker Container, reset it, but I don't think this is the right way.

Is there a way to modify /etc/mysql/my.cnf inside Docker Container without using docker-compose.yml?

Comment: You shouldn't generally directly edit files inside containers: it's very routine to need to delete and recreate them (to change options or update their image) and those changes will get lost.  The linked question describes how to use a copy of the `my.cnf` file from the host in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "docker config" to manage your configuration.

```
$ docker config --help
 Usage: docker config COMMAND

 Manage Docker configs

 Options:

 Commands:
 create Create a configuration file from a file or STDIN as content
 inspect Display detailed information on one or more config files
 ls List configs
 rm Remove one or more configuration filesRun ‘docker config COMMAND — help’ for more information on a command
```

You can create config and add or rm the config from the docker container. you can add configuration file to your docker container either using docker compose or using docker command.
Please check this awesome medium [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/about-using-docker-config-e967d4a74b83) which will help you to do hands on.